Excess kurtosis of binomial distribution
So I been at this for hours. I don't know where my simplification is going wrong but here it is:
$$\frac{n[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)p^4 + 6(n-1)(n-2)p^3 +7(n-1)p^2 + p] - 4(n[(n-1)(n-2)p^3 +3(n-1)p^2 + p + 6(np)^2(np + n(n-1)p^2 - 4(np)^3 + (np)^4}{(\sqrt{np(1-p)})^4}$$
From there I have -
$$\frac{n p (1-p)(1 - 6p + 6p^2 + 3np - 3np^2) + n^4 p^4 - 4(np)[n p (1-p)(1 - 2p + 3np) + n^3 p^3] + 6(n^2 p^2)[np(1-p) + n^2 p^2] - 4(n^3 p^3)(np) + n^4 p^4}{(np(1-p))^2}$$
How do I go from there? I have tried many ways to simplify this but haven’t gotten anywhere near $\frac{1-6p(1-p)}{np(1-p)}$.
I am trying to use the mgf and the $$\frac{E(X^4) - 4\mu E(X^3) + 6\mu^2 E(X^2) - 4\mu^3 E(X) + \mu^4}{\sigma^4}$$

First, note that $\frac{1-6p(1-p)}{np(1-p)}$ is the excess kurtosis, which differs from $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4\right]$ by $3$.
Rather than using mgf, I would directly use cumulant generating function, i.e., log of mgf,
$$C(t)=n \log\left(1-p+pe^t\right),
$$
which is more convenient. But all calculations can be done using mgf as well.
Successive differentiation gives
$$
C^{(1)}(t)=np\frac{e^t}{1-p+pe^t}, \quad \mu=C^{(1)}(0)=np;
$$
$$
C^{(2)}(t)=np(1-p)\frac{e^t}{\left(1-p+pe^t\right)^2}, \quad \sigma^2=C^{(2)}(0)=np(1-p);
$$
$$\begin{align}
C^{(3)}(t)&=np(1-p)\frac{(1-p)^2e^t-p^2e^{3t}}{\left(1-p+pe^t\right)^4}, \\ &\mathbb{E}\left\lbrace\left(X-\mu\right)^3\right\rbrace=C^{(3)}(0)=np(1-p)(1-2p);
\end{align}
$$
$$\begin{align}
C^{(4)}(0)&=np(1-p)\frac{\left[(1-p)^2 -3p^2\right]-4p\left[(1-p)^2 -p^2\right]}{1}\\&=np(1-p)(6p^2-6p+1)=\mathbb{E}\left\lbrace\left(X-\mu\right)^4\right\rbrace-3\sigma^4.
\end{align}
$$
Now excess kurtosis is
$$
\frac{C^{(4)}(0)}{\sigma^4}=\frac{np(1-p)(6p^2-6p+1)}{\left[np(1-p)\right]^2}=\frac{1-6p(1-p)}{np(1-p)}.
$$

so you don't derive the 3 from the E(X - $\mu$)^4. Do you add it seperately?

In most situations, it is the excess kurtosis that is convenient and is used in applied problems (e.g., being zero for normal distributions). If you indeed need the kurtosis, yes, we can just add 3 to the final result of excess kurtosis.
